# Support for multiple screens / tabs with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Lets say I have 2 different tabs, each one opened in a different screen (each tab has its own LWC). Is it possible to communicate between the two? In a way that an action in tab 1 will cause a result in screen 2?

I know how to do it with the JS API but I'm guessing Lightning Locker is going to block me? Have anyone tried it before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the use case for the [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation). It's [GA in Summer '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm). You can communicate across tabs or windows, between Lightning and Visualforce domains, etc. Everything you need to know is in the documentation.

> Use Lightning message service to communicate across the DOM—between Visualforce pages, Aura components, and Lightning web components, including components in a utility bar. You can use it to communicate between components within a single Lightning page or across multiple pages. If you’re switching from Salesforce Classic to Lightning Experience, you can now build Lightning web components that can communicate with existing Visualforce pages and Aura components. You can also use Lightning message service to communicate with softphones via Open CTI.

Comment: Thanks! will check this out!

Comment: "across tabs" means, browser tabs or console tabs? I thought we can't use LMS to communicate across browser tabs.